# PDF editing in Notepad++

Tags: pdf, notepad++

When I edit some properties of my PDF file in Notepad++ and save it, it can be read and opened in Adobe PDF reader or Acrobat but it will not open in different readers like Ashampoo: it popups with an error: "Page Tree missing from Dictionary".
Can it be that Notepad++ places hidden signs or something else?

Comment: Welcome to SU. PDF file format is standardized, it needs to contain certain elements to be valid. When you edit the properties you're somehow corrupting the file structure. You should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774896/edit) the question to clarify what properties exactly you edit, how you edit them and how exactly you save the file after modifications as NP++ doesn't save in PDF format by default. An example file might also help.

Comment: PDF is a binary format, and it contains a cross-reference table which tells it where to find the objects using the offset from the beginning of the file. Altering the number of bytes in any object will make the xref table invalid, and this includes (for example) CR/LF translation. You can't really edit PDF file contents without a great deal of care, starting off by using a binary editor and not modifying the number of bytes. Some PDF consumers can repair the damage, depending on how bad it is, and some (helloooo Acrobat) will do so without telling you.....

Comment: You can use either `qpdf` or `cpdf` to repair the file after these sorts of changes, simply by reading and writing the file. However, to provide advice on whether you should be doing this at all, we need a better description of what you are trying to change. And, as another commenter points out, we need to know if Notepad++ is making any changes of its own - for example, altering line endings. Because altering line endings in the middle of a binary section in a PDF is not going to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the "Diff" of the Original Document & the new Document. That will show your Intentional Changes + the UnIntentional Changes by your Editor.

Your Editor might having various Settings , Eg : Change line Endings , Change between tabs & Spaces , Default Character Encodings , Auto-Indentation , ETC. That will mess up the Document.

Comment: Thanks. But why is opening the file in an Adobe product possible without problem and opening in a different reader not, and in Aschampoo I get the error  "Page Tree missing from Dictionary"?

Comment: The Adobe product is silently fixing the file by reading the objects from the beginning and rewriting the cross-reference table. You will see that when the file is opened in Adobe Reader, for example, it is immediately marked as having been edited - so if you try to close it, you will be asked if you want to save it. This editing is the silent fixes which have been done. Your other products are unable to fix malformed files like yours, so refuse to open them.

Comment: When HTML Document (or JavaScript) is broken , web browsers still try to show some output web-page , though there may be errors logged somewhere. Similarly , when PDF viewer is trying to Process the PDF Document which is broken , then (A) It may try to fix the "minor" or "fixable" Issues to generate the output , logging the errors somewhere (B) It may terminate the Processing to throw the error. Acrobat is choosing (A) while Ashampoo is choosing (B) though I would prefer a middle ground (C) It may throw the error (so user knows something is wrong) & then try to generate the output. @TheoS

Comment: Correct , @johnwhitington , though the Silent fix may be Counter-Intuitive. A Warning may be useful to let users know about the fix.

Comment: Thanks all of you.
qpdf input.pdf output.pdf
fixed the file and is readable again in all viewers/readers